# Retrieving the data stored as text (YES/NO) via R from Bloomberg

Tags: r, bloomberg

How to get data stored in the text format (YES/NO) through R from Bloomberg? Ex. Need to get data for the "ENERGY_EFFIC_POLICY" field but getting this error:
Error in bdh_Impl(con, securities, fields, start.date, end.date, options,  :
Attempt to access value of element 'ENERGY_EFFIC_POLICY'(type: 'Float64') as 'bool' type.

**BDP:**

```
bdp("AAPL US EQUITY", "ENERGY_EFFIC_POLICY", "EQY_FUND_YEAR", "2016")
```

**BDH:**

```
library(Rblpapi)
library (float)
con <- blpConnect()

Sec <- "AAPL US Equity"

Para <- c("ENERGY_EFFIC_POLICY")
opt <- c("periodicitySelection" = "YEARLY")
ovrd <- c("BEST_FPERIOD_OVERRIDE"="FY")

E <- bdh(Sec, Para, start.date=as.Date("2015/01/31"), end.date=as.Date("2020/01/31"), options=opt, overrides=ovrd, con = con)
```

Comment: Can you change the date to character class with `as.character`

Comment: Also, which line of code is getting the error?  is it bdh or bdp

Comment: Have you checked the value on FLDS?

Comment: bdh code is getting an error @akrun

Comment: yes...I have checked...@assylias

Comment: I don't have access to the R implementation, but on other interfaces(python xbbg, Excel) the value comes back as 1 or 0 (which I assume R converts to a float).  Using BDH there and just having the override FUND_PER='Y' (no other overrides or options) gives me a history (of 1s and 0's). In the field description in Bloomberg FLDS, it implies that this value is stored as a string ("Y" or "N"), but that the Excel API returns 1 or 0. I wonder  if R is expecting "Y" or "N" from Bloomberg, but getting 1 or 0?

Comment: FWIW, I tested this using the lower-level C++ BLPAPI, which the R implementation relies upon (according to the docs). The data comes back as a float64. The question is WHY is R trying to convert the values to bool? The underlying api does not allow you to convert from float64 to bool as it loses precision, and this is the error you are seeing. I suggest: 1. Make sure you have the latest versions of the R implementation, and the BLP api. 2. Try your code with something simpler, like just the stock price of AAPL, PX_LAST, periodicity of "DAILY" and no overrides, and see if that fails too.

Comment: Oh, and I would ask Bloomberg: if I download the data in Excel, the value is 1 for say 28-Sep-2019. But in the Bloomberg terminal, using HP and Yearly period, the value for Energy Effic Pol is 0 for that same day. This data has only been added quite recently (as ESG is now a hot topic), so maybe you are the first to identify an issue with the way the data is stored in Bloomberg?